# Get permutations of all the array [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0]

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript, combinations

I am trying to create a script which generates all the various permutations of binary switches where there should be 5 `1` and 4 `0`. And the array should be of size `9`.

I tried the following code. The conditions for the permutations are:
1. The array set should be unique.
2. Not more than 3 `1` should be next to each other

```
const row = [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0];
const list = [];
const fullList = [];

// To make sure that no more than 3 `1` are next to each other
const isRowValid = (row) => {
  let isValid = true;
  for(let i = 0; i+2 < row.length; i++) {
    if(row[i] === 1 && row[i+1] === 1 && row[i+2] === 1) {
      isValid = false;
      break;
    }
  }
  return isValid;
}


const combinations = (row, baseIndex, currentIndex, iterationLevel, list) => {
  if(currentIndex > row.length - iterationLevel) {
      baseIndex++;
      currentIndex = 0;
  }

  if(baseIndex + iterationLevel > row.length) {
    baseIndex = 0;
    iterationLevel++;
  }

  if(iterationLevel === 5) {
    return;
  }

  let rowCopy = [...row]
  if(baseIndex > currentIndex ) {
    let first = [...row.slice(0, currentIndex)];
    let second = [...row.slice(currentIndex)];
    let value = second.splice(baseIndex - currentIndex, iterationLevel);
    rowCopy =  [...first, ...value, ...second]
  } else if(baseIndex < currentIndex) {
    let first = [...row.slice(0, currentIndex + iterationLevel)];
    let second = [...row.slice(currentIndex + iterationLevel)];
    let value = first.splice(baseIndex, iterationLevel);
    rowCopy = [...first, ...value, ...second];
  }
  if(isRowValid(rowCopy)) {
      list.push(rowCopy);
  }
  console.log(rowCopy);
  combinations(row, baseIndex, currentIndex + 1, iterationLevel, list);
}

combinations(row, 0, 0, 1, list);
list.forEach(l => combinations(l, 0, 0, 1, fullList));

// To remove duplicates
for(let i = 0; i < fullList.length; i++) {
  const base = fullList[i]
  for(let j = i + 1; j < fullList.length; j++) {
    const isSame = fullList[j].every((l, m) => base[m] === l);
    if(isSame) {
      fullList[j] = [];
    }
  }
}

let filtered = fullList.filter(l => l.length !== 0);
console.log(filtered.length);

filtered.slice(0, 100).map(i => console.log(i));
console.log(fullList.length);
```

[JS Bin](https://jsbin.com/dufemogapu/1/edit?js,console)

Comment: It is unclear what you are asking.

Comment: what is the expected output?

Comment: Do you mean permutations rather than combinations?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you meant permutations rather than combinations, where in each permutation there shouldn't be more than 3 sequential switches that are "on".

Whenever you have to generate permutations or combinations you can use a recursive backtracking algorithm.

The idea is simple, at every step you follow the possible choices until a base condition is met (e.g. permutation is complete because `perm.length === switchCount`). When taking a step you reflect that choice on the problem's state and when the recursive call returns you undo these effects.

In order to determine what choices can be made at each step we need to keep track of the problem's state. Here we only need to know how many on/off switches we have left and how many sequential on switches we have so far (`seqOn`).

```js
const perms = permute(5, 4);

console.log(perms.length);
console.log(perms);

function permute(on, off) {
  const switchCount = on + off;
  const perm = [], perms = [];

  p(on, off, 0);

  return perms;

  function p(on, off, seqOn) {
      if (perm.length === switchCount) {
          perms.push([...perm]);
          return;
      }

      if (on && seqOn < 3) {
          perm.push(1);
          p(on - 1, off, seqOn + 1);
          perm.pop();
      }

      if (off) {
          perm.push(0);
          p(on, off - 1, 0);
          perm.pop();
      }
  }
}
```

If we have many permutations to enumerate we can save on memory by using generators too. Here I yield the same `perm` array which saves the O(n) time copy. As long as you don't need to keep a copy and just enumerate switches it's fine.

```js
for (const perm of permute(5, 4)) {
    console.log(perm);
}

function* permute(on, off) {
    const switchCount = on + off;
    const perm = [];

    yield* p(on, off, 0);

    function* p(on, off, seqOn) {
        if (perm.length === switchCount) {
            yield perm;
            return;
        }

        if (on && seqOn < 3) {
            perm.push(1);
            yield* p(on - 1, off, seqOn + 1);
            perm.pop();
        }

        if (off) {
            perm.push(0);
            yield* p(on, off - 1, 0);
            perm.pop();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This is such an elegant solution

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan Thanks! Added a variant using generators which can be interesting ;)

Comment: @plalx Thanks for correcting, I meant permutations and not combinations. And the solution is well explained and the generator function is great.

Comment: @Sumit Just curious. Was this for a real world problem?

Comment: @plalx yes. I am designing a game where I needed the list of all such permutations.